# Named web colours in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, colors

I've not used Bootstrap that much, only little bits here and there to layout columns on pages etc.

What I've tended to do is colour elements using an alternative stylesheet and rely on this to do the work for me.

After reading up a little, it would seem that Bootstrap usually prefers colors to be defined using its own [customisation](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) page, as opposed to the application's proprietary stylesheet.

However, what I'm trying to ascertain is if there is any restriction on (or problem with) the use of **[HTML named colours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#HTML_color_names)** within Bootstrap. I've searched Google and tried looking on the Bootstrap site, but there's no real info that I can see (though I seem to be getting swamped by fluff on Google).

Comment: Is your question why people prefer to use (for example) `#FFFFFF` instead of `White` when specifying color in Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better readbilty and for more consinstence Bootstrap had classified  some situation  and assigned  to this  situation a col .. normally to this colors are associate the values :

- success
- info
- warning
- danger
- primary
- default

you could assigne to this situation the color you prefere changing the related  hex code  .. but if important mantain the consinstenrelated  to the dfferent situations

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-contextual-classes

> Convey meaning through color with a handful of emphasis utility
>   classes. These may also be applied to links and will darken on hover
>   just like our default link styles.

```
<p class="text-primary">Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
<p class="text-success">Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula.</p>
<p class="text-info">Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.</p>
<p class="text-warning">Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.</p>
<p class="text-danger">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
```

Comment: I did read [this section regarding the use of colours](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/colors/), which is fine - there are a range of pre-named colour classes defined by Bootstrap.  My question relates more to the use of the predefined HTML colours with bootstrap - is there any reason why these are rarely (I haven't honestly seen one example of usage yet) used with Bootstrap?

Comment: If you look for the most use bootstrap template you can see that often the color are related  for aesthetic reason  .. so rarely this can match with predefined  HTML color

Comment: I suppose so. That kind of answers it. After a little more digging, I think that one of the things that has been confusing me is that many of the tools used to produce and tailor Bootstrap actually *convert* the literal colour names to their numeric definition. Also, much of the work is done using Less (which took me a little getting used to), in which it's much easier to work with numeric (be it hex or decimal) values rather than their textual counterparts.

Comment: Though this doesn't fully answer my question, it's close enough.  The answer, plus the comments below seem to form a more complete answer to my question. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Hello i hope i understood your Question right.

You are able to edit the Bootstrap Stylesheet. Bootstrap has Color-Classes like: danger, success, primary, default and so on.
These are applied on the HTML class attribute usually like this: `class="text-danger"` would give us a red colored text

or

`<button class="btn btn-success">Green</button>` this would give us a green Button which is already styled by Bootstrap because of the first "btn" class which gives the button a round border and so on.

These Colors are defined by a HTML Color Code you can edit these with HTML Color Names like "blue" or "red" or you can just use your own Color Code.

Or you can just rely on your own stylesheet.

Comment: *These Colors are defined by a HTML Color Code you can edit these with HTML Color Names like "blue" or "red" or you can just use your own Color Code.* - That's close to what I'm asking, but is there any reason why colour names are not more widely used in Bootstrap or is it, 'just one of those things'?

Comment: +1: Though not entirely the answer, it certainly made me think about the whys and hows. After digging, I discovered that it's mainly down to the tools that convert literal HTML colours to their coded counterparts that were the sticking points for me.  I wasn't really sure if the format was appropriate (i.e. HTML named colours), but, as you've stated, they seem to be fine. Thanks for your pointers, Tibix.